# Azure linux VM Port not open

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machines, port

Im trying an ubuntu linux vm on azure, and need port 9001 to be open on inbound.
but cant reach the vm from outside on other ports than 22.

I have enabled firewall in linux vm and have opened those ports I need:

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
9001                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
9001 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I have added an inbound rule in Azure (same place where azure created standard ssh inbound rule to control vm)

```
Priority:340
Name:Port_9001
Port:9001
Protocol:TCP
Source:Any
Destination:Any
action:allow
```

when I try to telnet to 9001, there is no connection. but 
telnet to ssh port 22 works.

Running this shows that linux listens at these ports too.

```
 ss -lntu
Netid         State           Recv-Q           Send-Q                      Local Address:Port                      Peer Address:Port
udp           UNCONN          0                0                           127.0.0.53%lo:53                             0.0.0.0:*
udp           UNCONN          0                0                           10.0.0.4%eth0:68                             0.0.0.0:*
udp           UNCONN          0                0                                 0.0.0.0:27018                          0.0.0.0:*
udp           UNCONN          0                0                                 0.0.0.0:8767                           0.0.0.0:*
tcp           LISTEN          0                128                         127.0.0.53%lo:53                             0.0.0.0:*
tcp           LISTEN          0                128                               0.0.0.0:22                             0.0.0.0:*
tcp           LISTEN          0                128                               0.0.0.0:9001                           0.0.0.0:*
tcp           LISTEN          0                128                                  [::]:22                                [::]:*
```

I have also tested with Azure network tool "Verify IP flow"

```
Protocol:TCP 
Direction:Inbound 
local ip: 10.0.0.4 
port: 9001 
Remote ip: ****my home pc wan ip*** 
remote port: 9001

Result: access allowed 
security rule: Port_9001
```

[picture of inbound rules in azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PBg5.png)
[picture of ip network flow test port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKHCv.png)

Comment: What happens when you try to connect to port 9001?

Comment: no connection, also checked with a port open tool, which says its closed.

Comment: Can you try from another VM in the same subnet or even from the VM itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "no connection"? What is the specific error?

Comment: the port 9001 is not open....cant reach the service im running on that port in the vm. and when checking with telnet it cant connect to it. nor can an online open port checker. If I do the same check with port 22 i can telnet to it, an see its open with the online port checker.

Comment: Only have 1 vm.

Comment: @tjohansen how did you resolve this?